# Why can't we use getUid() to authenticate with your backend server in firebase authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication

In this code snippet (firebase doc) they have mentioned do not use user.getUid() to authenticate with your backend server. use FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.

```java
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
    
    
getUid() // A unique user ID, intended as the user's unique key across all providers.   
getToken() // The Firebase authentication token for this session.
```

My requirement is.

1. First I will register user with firebase authentication method (Email and password).
2. I will save String uid = user.getUid(); in my own backend server once registration is successful.
3. User credit information say user balance is saved in my own backend server as key user.getUid().
4. User sign-in with Email and password and ask for his balance.
5. I will get user.getUid() from firebase and match with my records, if match found returns balance to user.

They said getUid() is unique user id but Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server.

Why so? Why can't we use getUid() to authenticate with your backend server??

Comment: did you find answers to your question ? I am planning to do the exact same thing and I don't find an issue in the thought process we have

Answer (score 20):

The uid is a unique identifier for the user. So, while it identifies the user, it does not authenticate them.

A simple corollary is that my Stack Overflow ID is 209103. Knowing that, you can identify me. But to prove to Stack Overflow that you are Frank van Puffelen, requires that you know my credentials.

The ID of a user is quite often exposed in the interface. For example, if you click on my profile, you will see my ID. This is necessary for identifying me. If you would also use that same ID to authenticate, everyone who had seen your profile once could impersonate you on the site. Not a good idea when it comes to security.

Comment: Thanks for your response and i understand your point. As per my requirement I'll be using getUid()  to identify the user (after they have been authenticated with firebase system.) Point #4. Once authenticated as user credit information is with my backend server, i will get getUid() for this authenticated user, search record against this getUid() in my DB and present to him. My question is do i have any security hole in this process?

Comment: @Frank, well actulally I am not clearly understand getuid() comment in firebase database samples in "NewPostActivity" final String userId =getUid(): . getUid how can be unique in a every time.

Comment: @user3559471 the server cannot trust the app.  How does the server know the app reported the correct uid?  The server can use the token id to limit the trust placed in the integrity of the app. The server gets the uid from the token after verifying it was recently obtained from firebase by the user rather than just pulled from thin air.

Comment: Adding to @Frank's response, please have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/#id_token_verification

Using ID Tokens conforms to the OpenID Connect Spec too.

Answer (score 3):

Take your requirements as an example, if you using `[GET] https://your-domain.com/api/users/$uid/balance` to retrieve user's data, then this API is not secured at all, anybody could get other user's data with a random $uid.

As the comment(firebase doc) recommends, `FirebaseUser.getToken()` will get a [JWT](https://jwt.io) token, you should validate the token with firebase Admin SDK in your backend, and that is the data you could trust.

And the method client-side method should update to `user.getIdToken()` by now.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens is the reference for more detail.